# Is it ok to use Allah's name as many say "Oh, my God!" or "Gosh"?

Tags: allah, respect

Do you differentiate between respectful and disrespectful use of Allah's name? Is it OK to use Allah's name in the same way as many say "Oh, my God!" or "Gosh" just because they are surprised?

Answer (score 1):

As an Arabian we actually say **'ya Allah'** a lot for different situations, so I think it's fine to say '**oh, Allah**' and I am sure you will not use **Allah** name in inappropriate situations.

Comment: This answer could use more evidences and elaboration to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Salam Aleikhum brother. We should use the name of God  (Allah ) respectfully and not unnecessarily  as it is said we should not use the name of God (Allah )in vain but in respect.Regarding  (Oh my Gosh) it is not the name of God it Is an expression.

Comment: If you use the expression "Oh, my God!" as an expression of surprise, do you think God's name is used in a respectful way? Could you use the name of Allah in a similar expression of surprise?